# Setting React key prop to dynamic components array after instantiating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a method that returns an array of components that can be comletely different:

```
renderComponents() {
  const children = [];
  children.push(this.renderComponent1());
  children.push(this.renderComponent2());
  if (something) {
    children.push(this.renderComponent3());
  }

  return children;
}
```

But of course I'm getting an error `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.`. I've tried to set key like this:

```
children.forEach((child, i) => {
  Object.defineProperty(child.props, 'key', { value: i });
});
```

But as it turns out React prevents extension of props so I've received `Cannot define property key, object is not extensible`.

So my question is next: is it possible to set key prop to each component in an array after instantiating of those components?

UPD: The real code is next (it renders a pagination with ranges like this `[1]...[5][6][7][8][9]...[100]`):

```
  renderPaginationButton(page) {
    const { query, currentPage } = this.props;

    return (
      <Link
        className={classNames(styles.link, { [styles.active]: page === currentPage })}
        to={routes.searchUrl({ ...query, page })}
      >
        {page}
      </Link>
    );
  }

  renderPaginationSeparator() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.separator}>...</div>
    );
  }

  renderPaginationRange(from, amount) {
    const { pagesCount } = this.props;
    const result = [];

    for (let i = Math.max(from, 1); i < Math.min(from + amount, pagesCount); i++) {
      result.push(this.renderPaginationButton(i));
    }

    return result;
  }

  renderPagination() {
    const { currentPage, pagesCount } = this.props;

    if (pagesCount <= 1) {
      return;
    }

    const children = this.renderPaginationRange(currentPage - 2, 5);

    if (currentPage > 4) {
      children.unshift(
        this.renderPaginationButton(1),
        this.renderPaginationSeparator()
      );
    }

    if (pagesCount - currentPage > 4) {
      children.push(
        this.renderPaginationSeparator(),
        this.renderPaginationButton(pagesCount)
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className={styles.pagination}>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I think the real solution is to just set the keys properly on your renderComponent1, 2, and 3. Could you also share the code for those components?

Comment: "should" is not "must" ...

Comment: @AndrewSteinheiser added a real code

Comment: @JonasWilms yes, but it's not a solution to just ignore it. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you can use [`React.cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) to add props onto an already instantiated component.

But that's not what you should do in this case.

In your case, you should have `renderPaginationButton()` to return a `<Link>` element with `key=` prop already put in.

Comment: Yeah, I rethinked an architecture and moved all this logic to a separate component and added `key` prop to each link explicitly. I just wanted to avoid passing some key argument to `renderSeparator` method but now it seems not so bad for me. )